# How can i use firebase ML kit for match images?

Tags: firebase, firebase-mlkit

I'll explain my problem using an example,
I want to let the user take a selfie and save it on the device before the user uploads his profile picture to firebase storage. Then I want to match every profile picture with that selfie before he uploads it(*I need to prevent uploading fake profile photos*). Is it possible to do this with the Firebase ML kit(on-Device)?

Comment: Although ML Kit provides a [Face Contour API](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection#example_2_face_contour_detection), we do not provide any face recognition or face likeness functionality. You could potentially build something on top of the key points that are detected, but we don't have specific guidance here.

Comment: Adding to the last comment, firebase ML Kit is now deprecated and replaced by Google ML Kit.  Please see the migration guide here: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration